# Atom snippets not working with scss multiline snippet

Tags: sass, atom-editor, cson

I am trying to get working my custom snippets in Atom editor. This is my snippets.cson file:

```
# Your snippets
#
# Atom snippets allow you to enter a simple prefix in the editor and hit tab to
# expand the prefix into a larger code block with templated values.
#
# You can create a new snippet in this file by typing "snip" and then hitting
# tab.
#
# An example CoffeeScript snippet to expand log to console.log:
#
# '.source.coffee':
#   'Console log':
#     'prefix': 'log'
#     'body': 'console.log $1'
#
# Each scope (e.g. '.source.coffee' above) can only be declared once.
#
# This file uses CoffeeScript Object Notation (CSON).
# If you are unfamiliar with CSON, you can read more about it in the
# Atom Flight Manual:
# https://atom.io/docs/latest/using-atom-basic-customization#cson
'.text.html.basic':
  'Bootstrap css link':
    'prefix': 'bootstrap'
    'body': '<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">$1'

  'Vue minified':
    'prefix': 'vuemin'
    'body': '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.min.js"></script>$1'

  'Vue develompent':
    'prefix': 'vuedev'
    'body': '<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>$1'

  'Placehold img':
    'prefix': 'ph'
    'body': '<img src="https://placehold.it/$1" alt="">'
  'Telephone':
    'prefix': 'tel'
    'body': '<a href="tel:+48888888888$1">+48 888 888 888</a>'

'.source.css.scss':
  'Breakpoint Foundation':
    'prefix': 'bp'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint($1) {
        $2
      }
    """

'.source.css.scss':
  'Breakpoint Foundation Medium':
    'prefix': 'bpm'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint(medium) {
        $1
      }
    """

'.source.css.scss':
  'Breakpoint Foundation Large':
    'prefix': 'bpl'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint(large) {
        $1
      }
    """

  'Kentico comment':
    'prefix': 'kc'
    'body': '/*#$1#*/'
```

Everything works ok except this part:

```
'.source.css.scss':
  'Breakpoint Foundation':
    'prefix': 'bp'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint($1) {
        $2
      }
    """

'.source.css.scss':
  'Breakpoint Foundation Medium':
    'prefix': 'bpm'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint(medium) {
        $1
      }
    """

'.source.css.scss':
  'Breakpoint Foundation Large':
    'prefix': 'bpl'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint(large) {
        $1
      }
    """
```

When I editing scss file, only `bpl` and `kc` snippet is working.
I have 1.10.0 Atom with 1.11.0 autocomplete-snippets and 1.0.2 snippets plugins.

Comment: You should probably shorten the example and remove all comments and snippets that are not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group all snippets that share the same scope, otherwise previous instances get overwritten by later ones.

**Example**:

```
'.source.css.scss':
  'Breakpoint Foundation':
    'prefix': 'bp'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint($1) {
        $2
      }
    """
  'Breakpoint Foundation Medium':
    'prefix': 'bpm'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint(medium) {
        $1
      }
    """
  'Breakpoint Foundation Large':
    'prefix': 'bpl'
    'body': """
      @include breakpoint(large) {
        $1
      }
    """
```

One might argue that Atom should merge these keys, but that bears [discussion](https://github.com/atom/snippets/issues) with the developers.